# When trying to run Insert query in MySql using Task.Run(), it throws the follow exception: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

Here is the code:

```
static void Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e) //Event Handler
{
   Time timeToSend = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Time>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));

   Task.Run(async () => await SendToMySql(timeToSend));            
}
```

In the SendToMySql method, it basically a insert, as follows:

```
private static async Task SendToMySql(Time timeToSend)
{
        try
        {
            var connection = new MySqlConnection(string.Format(configuration["MySql:ConnectionString"], configuration["MySql:DataBaseName"]));
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            string query = "insert into resource_log (resource_value_log, creation_date) values ('" + timeToSend.Message + "',STR_TO_DATE( '" + DateTime.Now + "', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'))";
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            await connection.CloseAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
 }
```

I called this method using the Task.Run() cause i wanted it too run asynchronous if necessary. But it throws the following exception:

> "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

Here is the inner Exception:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Some of the data was actually inserted into the MySql.

I am new to asynchronous and parallel programming and I coded this way but I wonder if this is the right way to do a asynchronous query on MySql. I did it the same way as this, but with MongoDb, and it worked fine. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Try `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync`. And I don't think you need to code like this. Just do normal `Connection.Open. .  . .Close` Only run the method itself asynchronously.

Comment: You're not calling `.Dispose()` on your `MysqlConnection` and your `MySqlCommand`. This may or may not explain why it fails after a while

Comment: I changed to ExecuteNonQuery and to Open and Close, but it throws the same exception. It only works without throwing the exception if I do not use Task.Run(), but I want it to run parallel.

Comment: Also, your MySQL database has a limit of concurrent connections. If you start a lot of those tasks in parallel, some will have to wait for a connection to be freed, which could cause timeouts

Comment: I added the following code:

Comment: cmd.Dispose();
connection.Dispose();

Comment: But it still throws the same exception. @KevinGosse you said that MySql has a limit of concurrent connections, what would you sugest to solve that issue? I was thinking of something like a buffer.

Comment: @GuiOliveira You need some kind of producer/consumer implementation. You can use the `ActionBlock` from the TPL DataFlow, which does that out of the box: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.1

Comment: I started testing the code, and apperently the problem is precisely because of MySql not being able to deal with too many request, I came up with this conclusion cause with lesser request, there is no exception. @KevinGosse could you please be a little more specificy about your sugestion, using ActionBlock?

Comment: It's a longstanding bug in Connector/NET (MySql.Data) that none of the `Async` methods actually execute synchronously: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111 To fix this, you can switch to an alternative ADO.NET MySQL library, which is 100% async: https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/

Comment: @BradleyGrainger this ADO.NET MySQL is not a Nuget Package right?

Comment: @GuiOliveira it is on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Comment: @BradleyGrainger thank you very much, now it's working fine. If you post a response I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: MySqlConnector also has a bug in it related to disposing command while reader still active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a longstanding bug in Connector/NET (MySql.Data) that none of the `Async` methods actually execute asynchronously: [bug 70111](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111).

To fix this, you can switch to an alternative ADO.NET MySQL library, which is 100% async: MySqlConnector on [GitHub](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/).

Although MySqlConnector does implement a `CloseAsync` method, the default implementation synchronously returns the open connection to the connection pool, so I would recommend omitting the `CloseAsync` call and just using a `using` block to `Dispose` the connection when you're done with it:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(string.Format(configuration["MySql:ConnectionString"], configuration["MySql:DataBaseName"])))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    var query = "...";
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
        await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
}
```